# Langlands' original observation about Ramanujan conjecture

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Obviously functoriality of arbitrary high symmetric power lifts of automorphic forms on GL(2) will lead to the Ramanujan conjecture. But I guess that is too strong for Ramanujan. I came across some statement online some months back that Langlands observed something much weaker(but still about symmetric powers) will also imply Ramanujan conjecture.

What's Langlands' original observation?

Answer (score 9):

In Section 5.2 of *The role of the Ramanujan Conjecture in analytic number theory* by V. Blomer and F. Brumley, Bulletin AMS 50 (2013) 267--320, the authors write:

> There is perhaps no better illustration of the fundamental role of $L$-functions in this subject than the observation (due to Langlands) that the absolute convergence of $L(s,\pi,\mathrm{sym}^k)$ on $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$ for all $k\ge 2$ implies the Ramanujan conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}_2$.

Comment: One really needs only the holomorphy of these symmetric powers in Re$(s)>1$ (rather than absolute convergence -- of course, once Ramanujan follows then holomorphy becomes absolute convergence).  The letter from Serre to Deshouillers which is reproduced in the Blomer-Brumley article gives a sketch  argument, which Serre attributes to Langlands and Deligne.  See also page 666 of this article by Sarnak: http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/FieldNotesCurrent.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am not an expert at all, so I just copied the statement.

Answer (score 5):

Aurel has already given a good answer to this, and as I note in my comment to his answer one needs only the holomorphy of $L(s,\pi, \text{sym}^k)$ in the region Re$(s)>1$ to obtain the Ramanujan conjecture.  The argument is described in Section 8 of Langlands's paper: [Problems in the theory of automorphic forms](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/problems-ps.pdf).